# How To Invoke Rugged Check_connection Via ssh?

Tags: ssh, libgit2, rugged

Below is a Ruby program that is supposed to verify a connection with my GitHub repos, private and public.

The `ssh` key is the correct one, and it has no passphrase. However, ssh is apparently not used, as shown near the end of this question.

```rb
require 'pathname'
require 'rugged'

base = ARGV[0] || '.'
base_fq = Pathname.new(base).realpath.to_s
repo = Rugged::Repository.new base_fq
puts repo.inspect
remote = repo.remotes['origin']
puts "remote.name=#{remote.name}, remote.url=#{remote.url}, remote.fetch_refspecs=#{remote.fetch_refspecs}"
credentials = Rugged::Credentials::SshKey.new(
  username:   'git',
  passphrase: nil,
  privatekey: File.expand_path('~/.ssh/id_rsa'),
  publickey:  File.expand_path('~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub')
)
puts credentials.inspect

success = remote.check_connection(:fetch, credentials: credentials)
puts "remote.check_connection(:fetch, credentials: credentials) returned #{success}"

success = remote.fetch(credentials: credentials)
puts "remote.fetch(credentials: credentials) returned #{success}"
```

Output is:

````
#<Rugged::Repository:60 {path: "/mnt/c/work/ruby/update/.git/"}>
remote.name=origin, remote.url=git@github.com:mslinn/update.git, remote.fetch_refspecs=["+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"]#<Rugged::Credentials::SshKey:0x00007fee350db648 @username="git", @publickey="/home/mslinn/.ssh/id_rsa.pub", @privatekey="/home/mslinn/.ssh/id_rsa", @passphrase=nil>
remote.check_connection(:fetch, credentials: credentials) returned false
lib/check_connection.rb:21:in `fetch': unsupported URL protocol (Rugged::NetworkError)
        from lib/check_connection.rb:21:in `<main>'```
````

Why does `check_connection` always return `false`? Presumably that is also the reason the `fetch` raises an exception.

### Connecting Via ssh

I can connect via `ssh`:

```
$ ssh github.com
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi mslinn! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

My `~/.ssh/config` file contains:

```
Compression yes
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
XAuthLocation /usr/bin/xauth

Host github.com
  User git
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
```

I discovered that `libgit2` uses `libssh2` for `ssh` support.
However, `libssh2` does not read config settings from `~/.ssh/config`, so `libgit2` does not support that either.

### libssh2 Limitation

I found [this](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/#libgit2-and-other-git-clients) on the GitHub blog:

> If you’re using libgit2 or another piece of code using libssh2, we recommend you use libssh2 1.9.0 or newer and an ECDSA key, since it does not yet support RSA with SHA-2. Similarly, the Go SSH client also doesn’t yet support RSA with SHA-2, so we recommend using an Ed25519 key there.

I am using an RSA with SHA-2 key, which might be the problem:

```
$ ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
1024 SHA256:Xdv1AE4QTd0NfrwOGVTamF/wxnvFufCtsOIoOXtX5Mw Administrator@CHLOE (RSA)
```

### Missing libgit2 ssh Feature

[Here](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/libgit2/rugged/Rugged#features-class_method) is how to discover the features that `libgit2` was built with:

```rb
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'rugged'
=> true

irb(main):002:0> Rugged.libgit2_version
=> [1, 6, 3]

irb(main):003:0> Rugged.features
=> [:threads, :https]
```

The above output shows the library is up-to-date (version 1.6.3), but it was not built with `:ssh`, so that is definitely a problem. I'll have to [build the library](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/2665) to include that feature.

```bash
$ gem install rugged -- --with-ssh
Building native extensions with: '--with-ssh'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed rugged-1.6.3

$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'rugged'
=> true

irb(main):002:0> Rugged.features
=> [:threads, :https, :ssh]
```

### ssh Not Used

I configured the `git` `ssh` command to increase verbosity:

```bash
$ git config core.sshCommand "ssh -vi ~/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

Now when I type `git pull`, the expected ssh debug information is displayed. However, this does not affect the output of my test program.
Two possibilities:

1. Perhaps `libgit2` (and hence `rugged`) does not use the system `ssh`? After digging around on the Interwebs I believe this is true.
2. Perhaps `libgit2` (and hence `rugged`) does not support the `core.sshCommand` setting?

### ssh-agent

No agent is required for `git`, it is optional, and I was not using one:

```
$ ssh-add -L
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

I set up ssh-agent and tried again:

```
$ eval $(ssh-agent) > /dev/null

$ ssh-add
Identity added: /home/mslinn/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/mslinn/.ssh/id_rsa)

$ ssh-add -l
1024 SHA256:Xdv1AE4QTd0NfrwOGVTamF/wxnvFufCtsOIoOXtX5Mw 
/home/mslinn/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)

$ echo $SSH_AGENT_PID
2196
```

Then I changed the Ruby program to compute `credentials` using `ssh-agent`:

```rb
credentials = Rugged::Credentials::SshKeyFromAgent.new(username: 'git')
```

However, the Ruby program failed as before. Here is the output:

```
#<Rugged::Repository:60 {path: "/var/work/ruby/update/.git/"}>
remote.name=origin, remote.url=git@github.com:mslinn/update.git, remote.fetch_refspecs=["+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"]
#<Rugged::Credentials::SshKeyFromAgent:0x00007fa290d169d0 @username="git">
remote.check_connection(:fetch, credentials: credentials) returned false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clambering over hill and dale, the problem was that `libgit2` as provided by the `rugged` gem does not include `ssh` support. I showed how to do that above by using the `gem` command.

Bundler can also be configured to build `libgit2` with `ssh` support:

```bash
$ bundle config set --global build.rugged --with-ssh
```

After typing the above, the next time you run `bundle install` on a Ruby project that specifies `rugged` as a dependency, if the resolved version of `rugged` is not installed, it will be built with `ssh` support.

Once the above was done, the problem went away:

```
$ ruby lib/check_connection.rb
#<Rugged::Repository:60 {path: "/var/work/ruby/update/.git/"}>
remote.name=origin, remote.url=git@github.com:mslinn/update.git, remote.fetch_refspecs=["+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"]
#<Rugged::Credentials::SshKey:0x00007f13c7adecd8 @username="git", @publickey="/home/mslinn/.ssh/id_rsa.pub", @privatekey="/home/mslinn/.ssh/id_rsa", @passphrase=nil>
remote.check_connection(:fetch, credentials: credentials) returned true
```

It is probably a good idea to add this to every `rugged` project:

```rb
abort "Error: Rugged was not built with ssh support" \
  unless Rugged.features.include? :ssh
```

For more information, see [Working With Git Repos Using Ruby's Rugged Gem](https://www.mslinn.com/git/4400-rugged.html).